# My work laptop uses company DNS even when I'm not at work

Tags: windows-7, dns

My company gave me a laptop for work and I've noticed that it is using my company's DNS servers even when I'm at home and not on a VPN. I noticed this because I typed a search term in Firefox, which usually does a Google I'm feeling lucky search when there is no DNS result. I also see weird requests going out in Wireshark. I could provide more info if necessary. The IP settings are set to obtain a DNS server automatically. Where could it be picking up this setting?

Comment: What are the DNS server addresses?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible your laptop is caching previous dns results. 
Depending upon which OS you have you might try other things, but in Windows

at a command prompt type:    ipconfig /displaydns (LAN local connection status DETAILS will show you this also)  to see where the dns records are coming from.

Possibly try:    ipconfig /flushdns to force a new dns lookup when you are at home using that dns provider

Figuring out what is being used for dns resolution will get you closer to fixing it. Thus John T is right to ask what dns address is being used first.

If your network device TCP/IPv4 properties is is set to obtain DNS server address automatically, you can always add your companies preferred dns server but also include others such as google   8.8.8.8 & 8.8.4.4  or opendns  208.67.220.220 & 208.67.222.222

Comment: something weirder is going on, i wonder if they installed something on my laptop. im connected at work and the dns server is a local address, i dont understand how it knows to use a work dns server for dns when im at home

Comment: local meaning a non-routable address? 10.x.x.x or 192.168.x.x? Your laptop will also cache previous dns resolutions, that is why ipconfig /dnsflush forces it to resolve them again afresh. Are there explicitly assigned dns servers or is the nic set to obtain dns servers?

Answer (score 1):

The network configuration allows a fixed DNS to be set.  Check `Control Panel` -> `Network and Internet` -> `Network Connections`.  Right click on your network interface and click properties.  This will require an administrator password.  The configuration will be in the properties for `Internet Protocol Version 4`.